# How to show only 1 object's details

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have 2 models. "generator" and "results". I wan to create a `link_to` , to this word details. In details, in must have generator and result's attributes.

Generator `has_one :result`, Result `belongs_to :generator`. Right now what i have in my Generator `show.html.erb` is render result form ( `TO CREATE n link RESULT with GENERATOR` ) .

I need another `link_to` , for example after i got both generator n result, i want to only display this particular generator n result with generator id = 1 for example. In other words, i want to see only generator with generator id =1 and result with `generator_id` ( foreign key = 1) and show in excel so that i can print them later
.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why do you mention excel? You want to be able to export to excel?

Comment: Yes i want to export into excel but before exporting, i want to show only 1 record instead of all records(like in index). For example i want to show only generator with the generator id =1 and result with (foreign key : generator_id = 1 ) . After having this page, in this page itself, there will be a button to export

Comment: Look at this https://gist.github.com/jhjguxin/3074080

Answer (score 1):

You can run the search condition for your controller action and only output the first value found

```
@generator = Generator.where('id = ?',params[:search_value]).first
```

Comment: erm i think u got it wrong. I mean i can display any ID number not neccessary 1

Comment: .first and .last are rails conventions which allow you to extract the first of last result of the query to the database. That does not imply  showing ID = 1.  Adding and ordering scheme and it allow you to define better which result you want shown .order("updated_at ASC").[...].last.  If it has to me rando, then do something like Thing.order("RANDOM()").first

Comment: ic.then how can i pass my desired id to search_value

Comment: define the question: what record you are looking for.  Then find that record by using search conditions as expressed in example above.  I asked model Generator to find records whose id = the given parameters for search_value  and pull out the first result found.